# Update current record with next record value in SAS

Tags: sas, record

I want to identify the time frame of a agent's job.
For example Agent 081 had a task aaa from 202012-202104, then it switched to task vvv from 202104 until now 202202.

I found this code:

```
    data want;
recno=_n_+1;
set Task_times end=last;
if not last
then set Task_times (keep=TIME_ID rename=(TIME_ID=TO)) point=recno;
else call missing(TO);
run;
```

The output looks like:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2temk.png)

It's not exactly what I want, I need to check also the Agents.

Does anyone know how I can add an additional condition checking wheter the Agent of the next row is the same or not?

Thank you.

Many greetings,
Ben

Comment: Please specify how the dataset `Task_times` looks like and what you expect as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do use AGENT as a BY variable.

There is no need to use POINT= option, you can just set the dataset starting from the second observations. You can prevent the data step from stopping too soon by adding an extra empty observations onto the end by including another dataset with one observation and no variables.

Use the BY group processing to decide when to ignore the value retrieved from the next observation.

Here is example:

```
data have;
  input agent time_id a_type $ ;
cards;
80 202012 aa
80 202104 bb
83 202012 cc
83 202102 dd
;

data want;
  set have;
  by agent;
  set have(firstobs=2 keep=time_id rename=(time_id=to)) have(obs=1 drop=_all_);
  if last.agent then call missing(to);
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    agent    time_id    a_type      to

 1       80      202012      aa      202104
 2       80      202104      bb           .
 3       83      202012      cc      202102
 4       83      202102      dd           .
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried this but it doesn't check whether the next Agent is the same or not. It just takes the Time_ID of the next record.

Comment: It does test if the next agent is the same. It will take the value, but set it to missing because of the BY statement and LAST. test.  If it does not work then post your data and code, either by updating this question or making a new one.

Comment: Somehow I have to add a condition statement checking whether the Agent in the next row is the same or not

Comment: The code I posted is checking that. That is what LAST.AGENT means.

Comment: Make sure to post text as text, not photographs.  I typed a few of your example records from the photograph so you can try running it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and get this result:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqMfl.png)

The output I need is:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFcKV.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This macro might be helpful - it doesn't show you the next record, but it does allow you to recall any previous record:  https://core.sasjs.io/mp__prevobs_8sas.html